# Hadoop Java: how to specify map key as one of the index of input split?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a input data that looks like:

```
3070801,1963,1096,,"BE","",,1,,269,6,69,,1,,0,,,,,,,
3070802,1963,1096,,"US","TX",,1,,2,6,63,,0,,,,,,,,,
3070803,1963,1096,,"US","IL",,1,,2,6,63,,9,,0.3704,,,,,,,
3070804,1963,1096,,"US","OH",,1,,2,6,63,,3,,0.6667,,,,,,,
3070805,1963,1096,,"US","CA",,1,,2,6,63,,1,,0,,,,,,,
3070806,1963,1096,,"US","PA",,1,,2,6,63,,0,,,,,,,,,
3070807,1963,1096,,"US","OH",,1,,623,3,39,,3,,0.4444,,,,,,,
3070808,1963,1096,,"US","IA",,1,,623,3,39,,4,,0.375,,,,,,,
3070809,1963,1096,,"US","AZ",,1,,4,6,65,,0,,,,,,,,,
3070810,1963,1096,,"US","IL",,1,,4,6,65,,3,,0.4444,,,,,,,
```

In hadoop job configuration I mention separator as

```
job.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ",");
```

Based on this, the key to `map()` becomes the first column of dataset

**Question:** How can I also mention that the key has to be `index[9]` based on the input line split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for this level of flexibility you need you own InputFormat, derived from FileInputFormat. 
It will be relatively easy to implement taking some existing CSV Parser. I am using OpenCSV (http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) and happy with it.

Alternative way to process the data might be hive. You can threat CSV file in the HDFS as external table and then refer any column separately. Having good capability to define UDF functions and own aggregation functions - many types of processing can be done this way.